# Bootstrap Header doesn't work for all end-users

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an internal reporting website that I launched recently. When I tested it among certain users I didn't have any problems. However, now I am finding end-users who can't get the bootstrap based header to work.

At first I though maybe it was the order of the references. I messed around with that for a bit. However, that made it worse. So I put it back to the way I had it.

I told them to make sure their JS was enabled. This didn't help. In addition, it doesn't seem to matter which version of IE they are using.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>



<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background:#ffffff url(@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/r_header.png")) top right repeat-y">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-fixed-top">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href='http://in.providence.org/sss/Pages/default.aspx'>
                                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/mast_logo.gif")' />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td><h1 style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:3px"><b>@ViewBag.Title</b></h1></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>

                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                         Projects <span class="caret"></span>
                     </a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Capitalized Hours", "HoursCapitalized", "Capitalization")</li>
                         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cross Charges", "CrossCharges", "Capitalization")</li>
                         <li>@Html.ActionLink("CC Project", "CCProjects", "Capitalization")</li>
                         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Capitalization", "Index", "Capitalization")</li>

                     </ul>
                 </li>  

                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Vendor Info <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vendor DashBoard", "VendorDisplay", "Vendor")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Purchase Order Dashboard", "PurchaseOrder", "Vendor")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Company 4 Vendor Dashboard", "Company4VendorDisplay", "Vendor")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Invoice Look Up", "Index", "Vendor")</li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Payroll <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payroll Dashboard", "Index", "PayRoll")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contractor Dashboard", "Contractor", "PayRoll")</li>



                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Position Control <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "HRChange", "Default")</li>


                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I am finding end-users who can't get the bootstrap based header to work` this is not very specific. What doesn't work? The menu selection? The formatting? Something else? Also, I'm wondering why you have a `<table>` inside the `.navbar`. Bootstrap's navbar supports menus without the need for add table markup. Regardless, the basic way to debug anything is to strip out all the pieces and to create a simple test case and then start adding back the markup until it breaks.

Comment: Hmm, the table portion was there when I picked up this site after the originator left. As for the specific problem, the when they click the drop down menu, it doesn't work. That portion is grayed out.